# I have a form with radio buttons inside an iframe inserting text to parents textarea. "Undefined" comes to texarea instead of radio buttons value

Tags: javascript, iframe, radio-button, onsubmit

If I make a form, and add an ONSUBMIT to that it gives UNDEFINED as an answer to the parent window "textarea" instead of a value from the RADIOBUTTON that is chosen. I would not want to change the javascript, because it works fine with a  that has onclick with a value, but is it possible to get the  to work with the same script? Or what should I do to make this work?

here is an example of my work:

index.html:

```
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type"
 content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
  <script type="text/javascript">
function hello(string){
// get the current text, add a newline if not blank, and append new
// text
var anchorText = document.getElementById('myAnchor').value;
if(anchorText !== "") anchorText += '\n';
anchorText += string;
document.getElementById('myAnchor').value=anchorText;
}
  </script>
  <title>joubadou</title>
</head>
<body>
<form>Cart<br>
  <br>
  <textarea rows="10" id="myAnchor"></textarea></form>
<iframe src="radiobuttontest.html" height="300"></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

radiobuttontest.html:

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>Title</title>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type"
 content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
</head>
<body>
<br>
<form id="myForm" action="" method="get"
 onsubmit="parent.hello()">If
you want a blue
car you can choose<br>
  <br>
  <input name="sex" value="Bensin" checked="checked"
 type="radio">Bensin<br>
  <input name="sex" value="Diesel" type="radio">Diesel<br>
  <br>
  <input value="add to cart"
 onclick="parent.hello('Blue car')" type="submit"></form>
<br>
</body>
</html>
```

If you please can help me I would be so clad!

Answer (score 0):

This is what happens when user clicks <kbd>add to cart</kbd>:

1. The onclick of the input fires, and the value of `#anchorText` is
   changed to 'Blue car', which is passed to `hello()`.
2. `onsubmit` fires from the form, and the value of `#anchorText` is
       changed to `undefined`, since `string` is not passed.

To fix this, just remove the `onsubmit` attribute from the form, and pass the radio buttons instead of a string, for example:

Add this `if` to the `hello()`:

```
function hello(string){
    if (typeof string === 'object') { // Checks if an object is passed instead of a string
        for (var n = 0; n < string.length; n++) { // Iterate through object
            if (string[n].checked) { // Check, if the current radio button is checked
                string = string[n].value; // Change the value of string to value of checked radio button
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    var anchorText = document.getElementById('myAnchor').value;
    :
}
```

and pass the radio buttons like this:

```
<input value="add to cart" onclick="parent.hello(document.getElementsByName('sex'));" ... />
```

Notice, that you still can use `hello()` to handle also strings, when a string is passed as an argument.

[A live demo at jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QrW36/). This fiddle is just an example to show how the code works in a single document.

Comment: I simply don't know where to put it, and I haven't got luck this far in quessing, so I must ask that where's the "beginning of hello()". I'm kind a beginner, so everything is not clear to me.

Comment: I opened this jaFiddle demo first with safari (which I'm using mostly), and It didn't work. Still object NodeList comes istead of "Bensin" or Diesel" but then I opened it with Firefox, and everything worked well. Any Ideas to get it work with Safari too? Thank you for your patiency!

Comment: @Karhu I'm sorry, I'm as familiar with Safari as with Antarctis, I've no clue... It seems that `string` is coming out raw from the loop. Maybe renaming the `string` to `str` helps? You could also `console.log(string[n].checked)` before the `if` within `for..n` loop.